# How to find out the current building task in a grunt .tmpl file

Tags: javascript, build, task, gruntjs

I assemble a single index.html file from an index.tmpl file with grunt.template.process().

Now, I basically have two different builds: A development build (unminified), and a release build (minified). Based on the task that I pass to grunt via `grunt devel` or `grunt release`, I want to change what script to inline within the index.tmpl. Right now, I do it manually, and uncomment the corresponding line depending on my needs.

index.tmpl:

```
<%
var ownJsFile = grunt.config('uglify').dist.dest;
//var ownJsFile = grunt.config('concat').dev.dest;
...
%>
```

But I would rather have something like:

```
if (TASK == 'release')
    var ownJsFile = grunt.config('uglify').dist.dest;
else
    var ownJsFile = grunt.config('concat').dev.dest;
```

But how to get the `TASK` inside the template?

Comment: If the project is open source could you share a link to the repo task(s)? Or just share more code from the gruntfile/tasks? If I understand correctly, it seems like you might be over-complicating things for yourself. But a little more detail would be useful.

Comment: striped down Gruntfile.js: https://gist.github.com/Dynalon/62248720b91f55ee0b27
As you can see, I use two templates, `index-slim.tmpl` and `index-fat.tmpl`, which use either the concat or the uglified .js file for inlining. I want to have only a single index.tmpl file, where I can access the task (`release-slim`, `release-fat`) via an if/else construct

Comment: I keep a text file in UAT and Prod at the same location, but different value for such kind of a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass arbitrary data to grunt.template.process(template, { data: ... } ) . For example, you can inject the task name using grunt.task.current.name. Here is an example:

https://gist.github.com/sheenobu/5722360

It doesn't matter if the task is registered twice under release-task and devel-task, as long as we don't repeat ourselves. That said, binding template behavior to task name is not the best. You could, instead, pass in minify=true or uglify=true to grunt.template.process.